# Javascrip iterating over a for loop - logic

Tags: javascript

Folks, I am extracting data from my collection into an array like so

```js
obj = [{
  "PlayerName": "Satyajit Sahay",
  "Points": 83.83,
  "Rank": 1
},
{
  "PlayerName": "Chirag Galundia",
  "Points": 75.69,
  "Rank": 2
},
{
  "PlayerName": "Kashyap Kapoor",
  "Points": 70.91,
  "Rank": 3
}]
```

Around 190 such records. My effort is to iterate the array in a for loop. Then identify if the points are the same. If same I am assigning the same rank or else I am assigning a rank +1. Here is the code written so far

```js
var ranking = 1
for (i = 0; i < obj[0].length; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && obj[0][i].Points < obj[0][i - 1].Points) {
    ranking++
    obj[0][i].Rank = ranking;
  } else if (i > 0 && obj[0][i].Points === obj[0][i - 1].Points) {
    obj[0][i].Rank = ranking;
    ranking++
  }
}
```

This works fine if 2 consecutive players have the same points. The minute the third player has the same rank it behaves weirdly. Can someone help?

Comment: what do you mean by same rank ? same as the previously updated rank value ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "behaves weirdly?"

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni  yes so if the 2 players have same points lets assume 50 each. The rank of the first player lets assume is 40 then the next player should also be 40. The player after these 2 players should then get a rank of 42. Which the code above is doing. The problem starts if 3 players are on 50 points each. Then its behaving correctly for player 1 and 2 and then instead of assigning the same rank for the third player its incrementing by 1.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon addressed your questions also above

Comment: it seems like you don't update the ranking for the case where obj[0][i].Points > obj[0][i-1].Points, despite the fact that you say the ranking increases if they are not equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume your array is sorted by points.

What you can do as algorithm is

1. start with second record (i=1), with ranking = 1, step=1
2. if score is less than previous record increase ranking by step and reset step, else increase step
3. assign ranking
4. go back to 2 until we have reach the end of the array

aka

```
let ranking=1;
let step=1
for(i=1; i<obj.length; i++){
   if(obj[i].points < obj[i-1].points){
        ranking += step;
        step = 1;
   } else {
        step++;
   }
   obj[i].ranking = ranking;
}
```

Some extras :

don't use `var` use `let` or `const`

don't forget you can start the loop further than 0, if everything has a i>0 it means we don't need the first iteration.

take a look at a array funciton (`forEach()` `sort()` `find()`, ...) they could come handy

don't use upercase letter to name your variables

Comment: this was my original code, but it doesnt work if three consecutive players have the same points.

Comment: in fact even for 2 players with the same points it doesnt work correctly. It assigns the same rank and then just increments by 1 and assigns the next rank, whereas it should skip the number in between

Comment: I did not understand that you wanted to skip i will edit sorry

Comment: oh. man so frustrating when will i have the IQ to think like this..spent the whole morning,,such a simple and elegant solution....thanks bud appreciate it :)